# Can't connect to Spring Boot app running on Docker locally

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-desktop

I stuck with the problem that can't open my REST Spring Boot app on `localhost:8091` in browser.
Here is my `docker-compose.xml` (everything is deployed locally on Docker Desktop):

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  postgres:
    build:
      context: services/postgres
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    command: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRESS_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRESS_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRESS_PASSWORD=qqq
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    volumes:
      - "db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
  
  
  app:
    build:
      context: services/app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    command: java -jar ./app.jar
    environment:
      - PORT=8091
    network_mode: host  
    image: 'my-java-app'
    ports:
      - 8091:8091
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  angular:
    build:
      context: services/angularfrontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    image: 'my-angular-app'
    ports:
        - 80:80   
        
volumes:
   db-data:
```

Spring Boot App starts normally on `8091` and connects to the database, but then I can't make calls to it's API from my local machine ("connection refused").
Angular app opens normally (on `localhost:80`), but can't make calls to `localhost:8091` Spring Boot app.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your configuration seems to be OK, it should be working. Only thing is confusing me is "network_mode: host". What for is it? Usually it works without "network_mode".

Comment: Without this Spring Boot app can't connect to Postgres (not sure why, but this is the fact)

Comment: What hostname are you using to connect to database? You should connect to Postgres from Spring app using it's hostname "postgres".

Comment: spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres

Comment: "localhost" is the reason why you cannot connect to Postgres database from Spring app. "localhost" for Spring app is SAME docker container, where app is running. You should change it to hostname of Postgres database, e.q. "postgres" (hostname of docker container equals to it's name)

Comment: BTW, you can define new database url by providing parameter in docker compose:

    environment:
        PORT: 8091
        SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres/postgres

Comment: After removing network_mode: host and changing spring.datasource.url everything works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219034/discussion-between-ekaterina-and-igor-bljahhin).

Answer (score 1):

The call from angular service container to localhost:8091 fails, right?
Try to override in your angular frontend container the call to the backend
use **app:8091** (this is how the backend service is called) instead of localhost:8091.
In the 'angular' container localhost doesn't translate to 'app' container.

You can't get from a container into a different container using localhost.
localhost inside a container will translate to the ip of that container.

Try to make in your angular application the call to the backend configurable, after that override that configuration in docker-compose using environment.
Also do that for the springboot app application.
I don't see in the environment that you override the call to the postgress.
Expose that configuration in application.properties and override in docker-compose, after that remove network_mode: host

Comment: The problem was in "network_mode: host" for Spring Boot app, it resolved in comments above.

Comment: I think is a workaround. What will happen if you deploy your containers in Kubernetes or Docker Swarm? Your containers may run on different hosts, so "network_mode: host" will not save you. 
I suggest to make your connections configurable to be easy to override.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `network_mode: host`, you don't need to specify `<source>:<dest>` because the app is listening on 8091 directly on the host network:

```
...
app:
    build:
      context: services/app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    command: java -jar ./app.jar
    environment:
      - PORT=8091
    network_mode: host  
    image: 'my-java-app'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
...
```

If you want to run the java app like the other containers, simply **remove** this line from the compose file and the network mode will default to bridge:

```
network_mode: host
```

Comment: Can't connect to Postgres without this

Comment: I added an example on how to define the `ports` for `network_mode: host`

Comment: Off topic: you must also be doing something wrong if you need to expose your database on your host machine. By default, the containers are deployed under the same subnet and they can communicate to each other internally. The only container that should be _published_ on the host should be the web-interfaces in this case.

Comment: actually...the `ports: 8091` is completely useless. I am editing once more.